# Magento 1.9.10 Multistore view give 404 only 4 of 6 website

Tags: magento-1.9

i have a strange errors i have magento not installed by me.

This Magento have 6 website with this mage run code: base, uk, de, es, fr, us

this magento is setup to lauch the index in subfolder with same code example /uk have an index lauch this command:

```
Mage::run('uk','store');
```

and this work but if i change any other language not working for example if i lunch

```
Mage::run('de','store');
```

i give a 404 not found.
in configuration have this set {{unsecure_base_url}}uk/
same in de store but not work {{unsecure_base_url}}de/

base (italian) and uk store work, why the other 4 not work? it's a bug? i can solve this upgrade 1.9.22? 
the strange is this site language change work one week ago but now don't work i try to server rewind but have the same error. no sense about this i recover all past db and all past files
i try to disable rewrite, and set store url after address option but nothing, i try to setup de store as main store but not solve. i try all i know but i can't understand.

any one have an idea about? i try to search every where i can find many guide about this but nothing about this problem. I can't solve this. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your home pages are setup for each store view in the admin.  `System->Configuration->Web->Default Pages`.

Use the dropdown in the top left to choose each of your store views and make sure CMS Home page is set to a page that exists.

Comment: I already check this all store have same page. can change it but not change 404 error. alla pages are set to all view. Thanks 4 your answer